# Ĉu "endi" estas transitiva aŭ netransitiva?

Tags: accusative, transitivity

Por traduki "*it must be a ordinal*", I would use "ĝi estendas ordinalon". Alia ebla traduko, laŭ mi, estas "ĝi devas esti ordinalon".

Nu, ĉu la akuzativo estas ĝusta kiam oni uzas "-end/i"-igitaj verboj? Tio estas, ĉu "end/i" verboj estas transitivaj aŭ ne?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La sufikso *-end-* kutime kreas adjektivon el transitiva verbo. Kiel ĉiu ajn adjektivo en esperanto, eblas laŭpaŝe krei netransitivan verbon el tio. Ekzemplo de [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/sufiksoj/end.html):

> pagi → pagenda = tia, ke ĝi devas esti pagata, tia, ke oni pagu ĝin

Eblas do ankaŭ krei la verbon *pagendi* el tio: *la fakturo pagendas*. Tia verbo estas ĉiam netransitiva.

Do via unua frazo ne funkcias, ĉar ne eblas *esti ion*, kaj tial nenio povas esti *estenda*.

Via dua propono ŝajnas pli natura, sed atentu ke la dua substantivo de *esti* ne estas objekto, kaj tial ĝi devus ne havi la akuzativon. Pli ĝusta estus:

> Ĝi devas esti orda

Comment: Bone. Kio pri "estendig/i", "ĝi estendigas ordinalon". Mi ne vere ŝatas la formrezulton, sed ĉu ĝi estas gamatike korekta laŭ vi?

Comment: Mi dirus ke nek “estendigi” eblas ĉar ĝi ankoraŭ enhavas la kombinon “estend-”. Se ne eblas _estendi_, nek eblas igi ion estendi. Eble oni povus diri “estigendi” sed tio estus netransitiva kaj ankoraŭ ne taŭgus por via frazo. Eble se io estas _estigenda_ tio signifus ke ĝi nepre devas esti kreita (estigita).

Comment: @NeilRoberts _estigenda_ ekzist(et)as en la efektiva lingvo (aktuale, 1 gugla trafo el Ipernity) kaj mi fojfoje uzas ĝin. Ĉu _orda_ aŭ _ordinalo_ estas pli ĝusta dependas de la kuntektsto. Pri ĉio cetera mi plene konsentas kun vi.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know.

> A root is not really a noun or adjective or verb until it ends in an
>   -o or -a or one of the verbal endings. To make a noun or an adjective into a verb, it follows that one simply changes the -o or the -a to a
>   verbal ending.
>
> **Is the result a transitive or an intransitive verb? Unfortunately**
>   **there is no way to tell.** It very much depends upon the particular case
>   and the traditions that have grown up around it. Ĵaluza, for example,
>   is essentially an adjective. Making it a verb, Zamenhof himself wrote:
>
> - Ĉu vi ĵaluzas pri mi? = Are you jealous of me?
> - Li ĵaluzos sian edzinon. = He will be jealous of his wife.

http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq120.html#sec12-4-6

Comment: Well, there _is_ a way to know, even according to the quoted text: “the traditions that have grown up around it”. In this particular case, the tradition is that _end_-verbs are intransitive (and the correct sentence _tio pagendas mil dolarojn_ doesn’t make _pagendi_ transitive...)

Answer (score 1):

Certe eblas krei verbon el la radiko -end-, samkiel oni povas fari per la radiko -ind-:

> Ĝi aĉetindas > Indas aĉeti ĝin.

Do mi *supozas*:

> Ĝi aĉetendas > Endas aĉeti ĝin.

Comment: Certe, tie estas citaĵo el Plena Analiza Gramatiko: "*enda: deve farota ( tuj respondi estas ende; ties liverodo estas enda); endo: io neevitebla; **endas: oni nepre devas ( endas tuj fari sangan transverson)**; endeco: neceseco.*"

Answer (score 0):

Sufikson -end- (aŭ verbo "endi") oni ĉiam uzas nur kune kun aliaj verboj (ĉi-okaze estas verbo "esti"). Kaj ĝuste pri tiu verbo onu devas demandi, ĉu ĝi estas transitiva aŭ ne.
Interalie, via elekto de vortoj estas iom stranga, laŭ mi. Simple "ĝi devas esti orda" tute taŭgus.

El vortaro.net:

***-end-*** Suf. signifanta: «kiu devas esti —ata aŭ —ita pro materia aŭ morala trudo; kiun oni estas devigata —i»